# curl and http2: how to test http2 support at command line?

Tags: http, curl

I'm running `curl --http2 -XGET "http://localhost:9090/index.html"`

where localhost:9090 is a local server that logs the details of the HTTP request. Looking at those logs, I see:

```
2023/03/23 18:50:27 GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9090
Accept: */*
Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
Http2-Settings: AAMAAABkAAQCAAAAAAIAAAAA
Upgrade: h2c
User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
```

Why is curl using HTTP/1.1 as a protocol despite me specifying `--http2`?

Comment: You didn't specify https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--http2-prior-knowledge